# Android TextView elements remain bound through loops

Tags: android, listview

I'm not even sure how to search for this one, but I'm guessing I'm missing something obvious?

I have a custom list view adapter set to display various textviews which are defined in xml.  Some of the TextViews are set 'visibility gone' as I don't want them to take up space unless there is data to provide.  Everything works fine, except for items that go in the invis fields *after* a row has input data.  In all cases, the data remains the same as the initial row that displayed it.

E.g.:

- Blank
- Blank
- "I'm a row!"
- "I'm a row!" <-- should be blank
- "I'm a row!" <-- should be blank
- "New data"  <--correct
- "New data" <--should be blank

I have tried (and failed on each):

- Reset the string that is input to null
- Set the textview to invis on each loop
- I have done this WITHOUT the holder and with - same result

I have not tried (and really don't want to unless this is the only way):

- Creating band new textviews via code

EDITED WORKING Code per @pskink:

```
   if (fullSubset.length() > 0 && counter > 1){
        holder.subsetBulkTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.subsetBulkTV.setText(fullSubset);        
    }else {
        holder.subsetBulkTV.setText(null);
        holder.subsetBulkTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Thanks to @pskink this works now -- by clearing the text And setting to invis, it seems to work.  If anyone can help me understand why it doesn't clear through each loop, I'd be grateful -- seems to me that it should...

Comment: Please post the full Adapter class. You might have misunderstand the concept of holder.

Comment: add "else" with setVisibility gone

Comment: @pskink - good idea, and this stops the repeated data from showing, but leaves the full space in the container.  I still don't understand why the textview is still bound with the data from previous though.

Comment: Sorry- the textview was taking up multiple rows within its parent due to the data still being stored within it.  Even though it was invis, it still pushed the height down.  Your solution, along with a clearing of the data has fixed it.  Thank you very much!

Comment: i said "gone",  not "invisible"

Comment: DoH!  And that resolves the space issue completely.  Thank you again.